# how to setup dynamically minDate and maxDate jquery for datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two datepickers in Jquery, the second datepicker values (min and max) should depend on the first datepicker actual value.

This is my code:

`<input aria-label="date" type="text" id="EffectiveDate" data-bind="value: EffectiveDate" name="EffectiveDate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" disabled="disabled" size="10" maxlength="10" style="margin-left:0px;" />`

`<input aria-label="date" type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" size="10" maxlength="10" style="margin-left:0px;" />`

Now, my Jquery:

```
        $("#EndDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true
        }
        );
            $("#EffectiveDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
                //autoclose: true,
                //minDate: 1,
                minDate: vm.MinimumEffectiveDate(),
                onClose: function (selectDate) {
                    // Set the minDate of 'to' as the selectedDate of 'from'
                    //$("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", (new Date(selectDate)).addDays(1));
                    //$("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", (new Date(selectDate)).addMonths(24));
                },
                onSelect: function (date) {

                    //var selectedDate = new Date(date);
                    //alert(date);
                    var min = date.addDays(1);
                    var max = min.addMonths(24);
                    //var endDate = selectedDate.addDays(2);
                    //Set Minimum Date of EndDatePicker After Selected Date of StartDatePicker
                    //$("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(date));
                    //$("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", max);
                    var selectedDate = new Date(date);
                    var msecsInADay = 86400000;
                    var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

                    //Set Minimum Date of EndDatePicker After Selected Date of StartDatePicker
                    $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);
                    $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", '+2y');

                },
                onchange: function (date) {

                    var selectedDate = new Date(date);
                    //alert(date);
                    //alert(date);
                    var min = date.addDays(1);
                    var max = min.addMonths(24);
                    //var endDate = selectedDate.addDays(2);
                    //Set Minimum Date of EndDatePicker After Selected Date of StartDatePicker
                    //$("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", min);
                    //$("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", max);

                }
            });
```

The problem is that when selecting the date in the second datepicker, it is not restricted, the minimum date can be before the date in the first datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#EffectiveDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function(date) {
            var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            if (selectedDate) {
                selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + 1); // Adding one day

                // Set minimum date for EndDate picker
                $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        }
    });

    $("#EndDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true
    });
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        

<input type="text" id="EffectiveDate" placeholder="Effective Date" />
<input type="text" id="EndDate" placeholder="End Date" />
```

This modification ensures that the minimum date for the EndDate picker is set to one day after the selected date in the EffectiveDate picker.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onchange`, you should use `onClose` in the options for the EndDate datepicker.